# How do I get access to user's google calendar feed

Tags: c#, .net, google-calendar-api

I want to insert certain items into my user's google calendar. I have been looking at this client library for GData:

https://developers.google.com/gdata/client-cs

However, it requires me to pass username(email) and password. I don't want my users to type in their email and password in my application and I store them in my database. It is very risky business. Is there any other way where Google would provide me token and I store the token in database for future access? Much like what the Facebook does?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, use the Google Calendar API v2 and read the section on [authenticating with the Google Calendar service](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v2/developers_guide_protocol#Auth) on which end points to call and how to call them.